# How to detect URL schemes with .handlesExternalEvents and NSAppleEventManager simultaneously

Tags: swiftui, appdelegate, url-scheme, swiftui-windowgroup, nsappleeventmanager

I have a SwiftUI-based Mac app with multiple `WindowGroups`.

#### 1. Opening different SwiftUI `WindowGroups` using URL schemes

To open those windows I am using URL schemes ([like described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66664474/3917662)):

```
WindowGroup {
    // ...
}
.handlesExternalEvents(matching: Set(arrayLiteral: "primaryWindow"))
```

... and then calling:

```
NSWorkspace.shared.open(URL(string: "myapp://primaryWindow")!)
```

☑️ This works just fine!

#### 2. Detecting URLs called from outside the app

I also need to be able to recognise and handle URL schemes called from outside the app, like `myapp://somePath?someParameter=1`. I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991072/how-to-handle-with-a-default-url-scheme/1991162) and set an event handler within my `AppDelegate`:

```
func applicationWillFinishLaunching(_ notification: Notification) {
    NSAppleEventManager.shared().setEventHandler(self, andSelector: #selector(self.handleGetURL(event:reply:)), forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass), andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL)) )
}
```

☑️ This works just fine, too, and my `#selector` method is called like you would expect.

#### 3. Problem: How to use `.handlesExternalEvents` and `.setEventHandler` simultaneously?

**Here’s where the problem starts:** After calling `.setEventHandler` my `WindowGroups` no longer react on called URLs and I remain unable to open new windows.

That somehow makes sense since I’ve registered an event handler in AppDelegate specifically for `kAEGetURL` but I have no idea how to implement both features simultaneously. Looking forward for your advice!

Comment: Why `onOpenURL` does not work for you?

Comment: @Asperi Because I have to stick `.onOpenURL` to a specific View (like `.handlesExternalEvents`) and want to receive and handle URL scheme events regardlessly of that. My approach within AppDelegate with `.setEventHandler` seems to overwrite the `handlesExternalEvents` modifier. Am I missing something here? How would you open a WindowGroup within `onOpenURL`?